# What do Ruby GUI SketchUp developers use to build SketchUp software?

Tags: ruby, desktop-application

I couldn't find any enterprise level desktop application which is built on Ruby. I know only Sketchup built with Ruby. What do Ruby GUI SketchUp developers use to build SketchUp software? I'm also wondering if there any good enterprise level app built on Ruby?

Comment: I don't think Google built Sketchup using Ruby. Sketchup supports Ruby scripting, it's different thing.

Comment: SketchUp was developed by startup company Last Software of Boulder, Colorado, co-founded in 1999 by Brad Schell[7] and Joe Esch.[8] . Google acquired @Last Software on March 14, 2006 for an estimated $15-45mm,[11] attracted by Last's Software's work developing a plugin for Google Earth.

Comment: If you know who are developers, why don't you ask them?

Comment: He doesn't have any account on twitter and linkedin. He is not part of the company any longer. I'm also looking for a good app that built on Ruby.